# Rails 4 - Pull data from external MySQL

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to connect external MySQL database into **Rails 4** and read data from there. So what i did so far:

- Create in `lib/primo_db.rb`
- Create model `models/accountstatus.rb`

**primo_db.rb**

```
require 'active_record'  
require 'mysql'

class PrimoDatabase < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
  establish_connection(
  :adapter  => 'mysql',
  :database => '...',
  :host     => '...',
  :username => '...',
  :password => '...'
  )
end
```

**account.rb**

```
require 'primo_database'

    class Account < PrimoDatabase
        self.table_name = 'account'
        def self.getdata

        end
    end
```

**And my question is:**

- How to test connection in console between them because when i run `Accountstatus.getdata` in rails console i get this error `NameError: uninitialized constant PrimoDatabase`
- And if i run `ActiveRecod::Base.connection?` it's returning `false`

I know that I'm doing something wrong so I'll appreciate any help with that.

***EDITED - SEE THE ANSWER TO UNDERSTAND WHAT I DID BELOW***

Comment: Try to rename your `primo_db.rb` file to `primo_database.rb` so that the name of the file and the class defined on it have the same name

Comment: Did you require `lib/primo_db` somewhere?

Comment: @Bustikiller when i rename the folder, it doesn't help, same error..
@spickermann i try that and i don't receive error when i type `Accountstatus.getdata` => `nil` but when i'm try to find something getting still error: doesn't exist: SELECT `accountstatuses`.* FROM `accountstatuses`

Comment: And? Does a table named `accountstatuses` exist in your database?

Comment: That's not really what im looking for.. dont wanna use local just be able to read data from external mysql db

Comment: @spickermann its just trying to connect into mysql to `accountstatuses` table, but there's just `account` and then `accountStatus` = ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql::Error: Table 'poll_useprimo_prod.accountstatuses' doesn't exist: SELECT `accountstatuses`.* FROM `accountstatuses`

Comment: When you have a model named `Accountstatus` than active record expects a tables named `accountstatuses`. If you want to use another name you have to configure another table name.

Comment: But if i rename it to Account i getting error: `NameError: uninitialized constant Account` and still it's gonna returning `accounts` instead `account`

Comment: Thats weird i change it back ti `Accountstatus` and now its working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright i know where i did a mistake.

- The file has to be named like a class in that file so for me: `account.rb` and class `Account < PrimoDatabase`
- Then there should be before the class `require '*.rb'` from `lib`
- Then i had to add `self.table_name = 'account'` to specify the table
- And call for connection is `Account.connection`

So then im able to connect to DB and pulling data from there.
Hope it helps to somebody.

***EDITED MY QUESTION TO CORRECT ANSWER***